# QProcess start Notepad++ with Windows "start" program

Tags: windows, qt, qprocess

I'm trying to open a file with Notepad++ by using QProcess.
This is the command I'm trying to start:

```
start notepad++ file.txt
```

If I run this command on the terminal, everything works fine, but if I use QProcess, the signal errorOccured() is emitted with error FailedToStart.

This is my code:

```
  QProcess* process = new QProcess;
  QObject::connect(process, &QProcess::errorOccurred, this, [process](QProcess::ProcessError e)
  {
    qDebug() << process->errorString();
    qDebug() << e;
  });
  QObject::connect(process, qOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>(&QProcess::finished), this, [process](int exitcode, QProcess::ExitStatus)
  {
    if(exitcode != 0)
      qDebug() << process->readAllStandardError();

    process->deleteLater();
  });

  process->start("start", { "notepad++", "file.txt" });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no application named `start.exe`, it only exists as an internal command inside cmd.exe.

To emulate `start`, use `ShellExecute(0, 0, TEXT("Notepad++"), TEXT("c:\myfile.ext"), 0, SW_SHOW);`.

If you absolutely need to use `QProcess` you would have to execute `cmd.exe /C start "" "Notepad++" "c:\myfile.ext"`.